# memoir section head styling with tcolorbox

Tags: memoir, section-titles

[image]

[image]

I want to clone the section head style of images above.

But I don't know how to styling section counter and section title separately.

Main challenges are:

1. Counter and title must be separated and boxed.
2. Title box must be auto-resized and title must be right-aligned.
3. Show the section counter as captialized alphabet only in the section head(they must be arabic number in other situation).
4. If title has multiline form, section counter must be anchored at north.

My MWE is here, which is not successful.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol,enumitem}
%\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{etoolbox,refcount}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\setstocksize{297mm}{210mm}\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\setmarginnotes{6mm}{0mm}{0mm} %4.454mm   %43.554mm %28.4 18.4 4.9     
\setulmarginsandblock{35.28mm}{30mm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{30mm}{30mm}{*}
\setheadfoot{20mm}{10mm}
\checkandfixthelayout
\newcommand{\wht}{\color{white}}
\newcommand{\cbcyan}{\colorbox{cyan}}
\setsecheadstyle{\huge\bfseries\sffamily\protect\cbcyan}
\renewcommand\thesection{\protect\cbcyan{\bfseries\protect\wht\Alph{section}}}
\setsechook{\setsecnumformat{\:\:\csname the##1\endcsname\:\:}}

\begin{document}

\section{DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS}
\begin{center}
    \colorbox{cyan!15!white}{A \textbf{differential equation} is an equation involving a \textit{derivative} of a function.}
\end{center}
Suppose $y$ is a function of $x$, so $y=y(x)$. Examples of differential equations for this function are:

\section{EULER'S METHOD FOR NUMERICAL INTEGRATION}
In the book \textit{Institutionum calculi integralis}, \textbf{Leonhard Euler} (1707 - 1783) described a method which allows us to numerically approximate the solution curve to a differential equation where $\frac{d y}{d x}=f(x, y)$ with particular solution $\left(x_{0}, y_{0}\right)$.
\end{document}
```

[image]